# mysql get sum of value and counts of users from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables like this. I need to get total votes and total comment given by users in one query

users table

```
id username
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    E
```

votes table

```
id user_id  value
1     2       1    
2     3       1
3     1       1
4     4       1
5     1       1
```

comments table

```
id  user_id
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     3
5     4
```

I need the result like this. I used left join. its double the result. anyone can help on this?

```
username   total_votes   total_number_of_verdict
A              2                   1
B              1                   1
C              1                   2
D              1                   1
```

Comment: what is total numer of verdict? what is the query you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this using left join

```
SELECT u.username,COALESCE(p.cnt,0) AS post_count,COALESCE(c.cnt1,0) AS 
post_count FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt,uid FROM
votes GROUP BY uid ) p 
 ON (p.uid = u.id ) LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS
cnt1,user_id   FROM comments   GROUP BY user_id ) c ON ( c.user_id = u.id);
```

[check here on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43efae/1)

if you want ignore which user didn't get commments and votes then use following query

```
SELECT u.username,COALESCE(p.cnt,0) AS post_count,COALESCE(c.cnt1,0) AS 
post_count FROM users u
```

`LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt,uid FROM`
 `votes GROUP BY uid ) p 
     ON (p.uid = u.id ) LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS
    cnt1,user_id   FROM comments   GROUP BY user_id ) c ON ( c.user_id = u.id) where cnt not in (0);`

[check here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43efae/9)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its works. I want to ignore the users who not give any votes and comments.

Comment: I meant the results shows if user not give any votes and comments.

Comment: I want to ignore those users from the list

Answer (score 0):

You should consider reading this:
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/
and let us know what you already tried...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserTable.Username AS Username, SUM(VotesTable.Value) AS SUMVotes, COUNT(CommentTable.User_Id) AS SUMComments
FROM UserTable 
LEFT JOIN VotesTable ON VotesTable.User_Id = UserTable.UserId 
LEFT JOIN CommentsTable ON UserTable.User_Id = CommentsTable.User_Id
```

And if you want, you can add a

```
WHERE UserTable.User_Id = @User_Id
```

All you do here ist to start at the Usertable, because this is your "highest" Datatable. Then you connect the other tables with their foreign keys `User_Id`.

In the `SELECT`Statement you simplay choose `SUM` and `COUNT` to get the Sum of the Votes and the Count of all Comments they wrote.

Hope that helps you understand how to build these statements. If there is any problems, comment and I'll update my answer. :)

Comment: @ShaƞkarSBavaƞ they do? :D I thought SUM() returns a Int. If not, you can `CAST` your Types into other. Something like this: `CAST(SUM(VotesTable.Value) AS int)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select u.username,
    v.total_votes,
    c.total_number_of_verdict
from users u left join (
    select user_id, sum(value) total_votes
    from votes
    group by user_id
) v on u.id = v.user_id
left join (
    select user_id, count(1) total_number_of_verdict
    from comments
    group by user_id
) c on u.id = c.user_id;
```

Comment: results show only if user gives votes and comments. I want to display results if user give at least vote or comments

Comment: @ShaƞkarSBavaƞ You just need to change `inner join` to `left join`. Updated my answer.